# Read big files in C++ but also small files as well in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I want to make a C++ program to read huge files (like 50Gb each) while you have only 4 or 8Gb of RAM.
I want this algorithm to be faster and work with small files as well.

This is the code I have until now:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
//Making a buffer to store the chuncks of the file read:
// Buffer size 1 Megabyte (or any number you like)
size_t buffer_size = 1<<20;
char *buffer = new char[buffer_size];



int main(){
string filename="stats.txt";

//compute file size
size_t iFileSize = 0;
std::ifstream ifstr(filename.c_str(), std::ios::binary); // create the file stream    - this is scoped for destruction

if(!ifstr.good()){
    cout<<"File is not valid!"<<endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
//get the file size
iFileSize = ifstr.tellg();
ifstr.seekg( 0, std::ios::end ); // open file at the end to get the size
iFileSize = (int) ifstr.tellg() - iFileSize;
cout<<"File size is: "<<iFileSize<<endl;
//close the file and reopen it for reading:
ifstr.close();
cout<<"Buffer size before check is:"<<buffer_size<<endl;
if(buffer_size>iFileSize){
        buffer_size=iFileSize;
}
cout<<"Buffer size after check is:"<<buffer_size<<endl;


ifstream myFile;

myFile.open(filename);

if(myFile.fail()){
        cerr<<"Error opening file!"<<endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}

if(!myFile.good()){
        cout<<"File is not valid!"<<endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}

if(!myFile.is_open()){
        cout<<"File is NOT opened anymore!"<<endl;
        return 1;
}

while(myFile.is_open()&&myFile){
    // Try to read next chunk of data
    myFile.read(buffer, buffer_size);
    // Get the number of bytes actually read
    size_t count = myFile.gcount();
     // If nothing has been read, break
    if (!count){
        break;
    }
    // Do whatever you need with first count bytes in the buffer:
    string line;
    while(getline(myFile, line)){
             if(!line.empty()){
                cout <<"Line: '" << line << "'" <<endl;
             }


    }

}
delete[] buffer;
buffer = NULL;
myFile.close();


return 0;

}
```

My files could have blank lines between the text line, also even the first lines could be blank lines.
So, I tested the program on a small file size (128kb in size) named to see how it works. But it doesn't work. It doesn't display any line on the screen even the file is so small.

What is wrong? Also, if I change the buffer size to a very small number, it reads just first one or two lines but why it doesn't loop to the end of the file to read and display all of the lines from that small file? Any help, please?

Thank you in advance!

This is the test file: (It starts with a few blank lines also.)

```
Population UK: 97876876723


Population France: 898989













This is the test end of the file: Yay!
```

This is the result:
And no line from file is displayed.
[image]

Comment: The shown code uses both `read()` and `getline()` to read the file. As Mr. Spock would say: this is not logical. That's what's wrong: you need to decide whether you wish to read a specific number of characters at a time, or line by line.

Comment: you read chunks into `buffer` but then you arent actually using the contents of `buffer`

Comment: Also, for "Get the number of bytes actually read" (in this iteration) you need the return value from `read()`, not `gcount()`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I want to read a huge file part by part without loading it into RAM since it is 50Gb and RAM is only 8Gb. After loading only just one single part from many into the RAM then I want to read it line by line and display each line on the screen. That is why I used read (for 1st step) and getline is for 2nd step, to read it line by line. How the algorithm should look like if I want to do these things? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I tried to pass the buffer as is to the getline function but it doesn't work. So I transformed it into a vector like this: size_t buffer_size = 1<<20;
std::vector<char> buffer(buffer_size+1, 0); and after that I passed it to the getline function as this: // Do whatever you need with first count bytes in the buffer:
    string line;
    while(getline(myFile.read(buffer.data(), buffer_size), line)){
             if(!line.empty()){
                cout <<"Line: '" << line << "'" <<endl;
             }
And it still doesn't work. Any help, please? Thank you!

Comment: @BenVoigt How to do it, please? I tried like this: // Get the number of bytes actually read
    size_t count = myFile.read(); instead of .gcount() but it throws the error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::read()' What you mean, exactly? Any help, please? Thank you so much in advance to everyone!

Comment: Once you "read (for 1st step)", then calling "`getline`" does not read what you've just read, one line at a time. `getline` does not work this way. I think you misunderstand what `getline` does. It doesn't give you what you just `read()`. That's not how `getline` works. Which part of "you arent actually using the contents of `buffer`" was unclear to you?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I tried to use the buffer data like this: while(myFile.is_open()&&myFile){
    //[...] //
    // Do whatever you need with first count bytes in the buffer:
    string line;
    while(getline(myFile.read(buffer.data(), buffer_size), line)){
             if(!line.empty()){
                cout <<"Line: '" << line << "'" <<endl;
             }


    }

}

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Supposing that  while(getline(myFile.read(buffer.data(), buffer_size), line)){...} will read the buffer (chunck) line by line but you say that this is wrong. How exactly to extract text from the buffer line by line if not using getline? I need to process ecah line further that's why I need it to read line by line.
I tried also to do while(getline(buffer.data(), buffer_size), line){...} and doesn't work either. Any help, please? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: The first parameter to `getline` is an input stream. Not a buffer. If you read 10000 characters from a file into a buffer, and then call `getline`, then, of course, `getline` will start reading the rest of the file, starting with the 10001's character, looking to read the next line of text. After all, the first 10000 characters were already read from the file. Why exactly led you to believe that getline would go back, somehow, to the buffer and read from it, instead of what's left in the file? C++ does not work this way. As Mr. Spock would say, again: this is not logical.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ok. You are right. But how to proceed further? How to parse each line, line by line from the buffer? How exactly to do it? Thank you!

Comment: One can always construct a `std::stringstream`, but that is going to involve a lot more copying around, and will likely negate any micro-optimizations one will gain from reading large chunks at a time. You have a big buffer with a bunch of data in there. Find each line yourself. Use pointers and algorithms. In general, you have a choice: fast or flexible (hoping that your C++ library optimizes a large read by directly calling the operating system functions, instead of still reading a streambuf at a time, and just copying each chunk into your buffer). But not both.

Comment: Please post the program output as text, not as image.